# Nginx не перезапускается при Docker build

Tags: nginx, docker

Создаю образ при помощи следующего Docker файла:

```
FROM        ubuntu:16.10

RUN         apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y nginx python3-pip

RUN         mkdir -p /home/app/
COPY        ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY        . /home/app/
WORKDIR     /home/app/

RUN         pip3 install gunicorn
RUN         pip3 install -v -r requirements.txt

RUN         service nginx restart
EXPOSE      80

CMD         ["gunicorn", "go2change.wsgi:application"]
```

При создании контейнера nginx не подает признаков жизни, хотя процесс запущен.

Если сделать docker exec и уже внутри набрать:

```
service nginx restart
```

все начинает работать как надо.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема, видимо, в недопонимании того, для чего служит <s>[*lxc*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC)</s> [*cgroups*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) ([*docker* сейчас не использует *lxc*](https://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/)) вообще и «обёртка» вокруг <s>*lxc*</s> *cgroups* под названием *docker* в частности.

а служат они для запуска внутри изолированного окружения **одного** процесса (когда этот процесс завершает работу, окружение уничтожается).

и если вам требуется в одном и том же окружении запускать **больше** процессов (в вашем случае — *nginx* и *python*), то вам нужно запустить некий «супер»-процесс, который уже запустит все остальные нужные вам.

[чаще всего](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/) в качестве такого «супер»-процесса используют программу [*supervisor*](http://supervisord.org/) (пакет с таким именем присутствует в репозиториях популярных дистрибутивов). хотя, конечно, можно (и тоже нередко встречается) написать мини-скрипт «на коленке», который запустит нужные вам процессы и будет ждать их завершения (если он сам завершится, то см. выше второй абзац).

---

#### дополнение про run и cmd

директивы *run* в файле *dockerfile* выполняются во время создания образа (*image*), но не во время запуска изолированного окружения (коротко: контейнера).

при запуске контейнера выполняется директива *cmd*.

Comment: Только там nginx и Python, симптомов Ruby не наблюдаю :)

Comment: @D-side, точно. я отчего-то подумал, что gunicorn написан на ruby. исправил.

Comment: Ну, почти. Unicorn на Ruby. Gunicorn, грубо, его аналог в мире Python.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать)