# Как правильно использовать Docker

Tags: linux, docker, виртуальная-машина, docker-compose

Пройдя туториал на офф сайте. Понял что штука крайне полезная и сильно помогает при разработке и развёртывании. Но всюду разные варианты использования.

На примере: есть web-сервис, python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn.

Как идиологически правильно организовать работу в docker?
Ставить все в один image или в разные? Какие плюсы/минусы разных решений?
А возможно лучше пользоваться готовыми images на docker hub?

Comment: оф. официальный, а не оффициальный.

Comment: @Etki это может быть сокращение от official.

Comment: @Denis сокращение от official это off.

Comment: @Etki а если лень переключать на английский, то офф.

Comment: @Denis то во рту росли грибы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. сущность в *docker*-е под названием «контейнер» предназначена для запуска **одного** процесса внутри окружения, где, благодаря [*cgroups*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), ограничены и изолированы вычислительные ресурсы (процессорные, сетевые, ресурсы памяти, ресурсы ввода-вывода). естественно, этот процесс может «плодить» потомков (которые «видят» только это изолированное окрежение), и этим иногда [пользуются для запуска нескольких несвязанных процессов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595770/178576).
2. > А возможно лучше пользоваться готовыми images на docker hub?

   вопрос не очень корректен: подавляющее большинство пользователей *docker*-а именно так и делает, не имея представления о том, как создать собственный *базовый* «образ» (*image*), и используя (с помощью директивы `from` в *dockerfile*-е) уже готовые «образы» как раз с `hub.docker.com`, лишь «надстраивая» их (или даже не «надстраивая», а используя уже готовенькие) с помощью *dockerfile*-а. и оно (большинство) отлично себя при этом чувствует.

   (к слову: а из тех, кто умеет создавать собственные *базовые* «образы», подавляющее большинство не имеет представления о том, как обойтись в дальнейшем без *dockerfile*-а, и тоже себя при этом отлично чувствует.)
3. > Как идеологически правильно организовать работу в docker?

   начните с реализации примитивных примеров, изложенных в документации. по мере накопления знаний и навыков вы сами придумаете себе «идеологию» (если захотите, конечно).

Comment: если вы не верите мне, что можно обойтись без *dockerfile*-а вообще (и, соответственно, не плодить мириады промежуточных образов), попробуйте использовать связку из `docker run` и `docker commit`, и я гарантирую, что вы узнаете о docker-е много нового.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно идеологии docker - одно приложение - один контейнер. Но я бы сказал больше - одна сущность - один контейнер. Вот допустим у меня дома есть owncloud, которому нужна база данных. Как следствие, у меня 4 докер контейнера: один для приложения (там апач+пхп), в втором постгрес. Еще два контейнера с данными (для вебсервера и базы). И когда нужно было обновить сам owncloud, я не боялся, что потеряю базу или сохраненные данные.

Если все свалить в один контейнер, то выгоды практически никакой кроме того, что не засоряется основная система. Но иногда это нужно - если хочется попробовать свеженький перл или очень древний пхп, что бы воспроизвести багу заказчика. На своей реальной машине часто даже ставить не хочется, а иногда и даже невозможно.

Разделение на части также выгодно, если нужно масштабировать. docker-compose (чудная надстройка над docker), который буквально в пару строк позволяет нужный контейнер "размножить", чем обеспечить обработку увеличенного количества пользователей. И самое главное, если разбить правильно, то увеличить кол-во определенных контейнеров может админ/девопс/автоматика и обеспечить безперебойную работу сервиса.

В целом - деление на части - это такая же сложная архитектурная задача, как и разделение приложения на классы и тому подобное.

Comment: *Согласно идеологии* — скорее, «технологии»: `dockerd` технически «не умеет» запускать и отслеживать жизнеспособность более чем одного процесса в одном изолированном окружении.

Comment: так технологии подгоняют под идеологию. Сам lxc, который по умолчанию использует докер, не имеет подобного ограничения.

Comment: сравнение, по-моему, некорректное: docker сейчас [не использует lxc](https://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/), который является в некотором смысле «конкурентом» docker-а. // да, конечно, *цель создания* программы можно, при большом желании, назвать «идеологией». типа: почему apache не умеет создавать файловые системы? да потому что у него такая «идеология».