# Как правильно создаются, запускаются и конфигурируются Docker контейнеры

Tags: linux, docker, devops

Пытаюсь освоить docker но пока что-то не получается. Читал статьи, но везде, все описывается по разному + порой возникает ощущение что авторы сами не понимают что делают.

С образами вроде разобрался, как я понял:
Образ - это сконфигурированное ПО с зависимостями.
Образ - создается/кофигурируется с помощью dockerfile.
Dockerfile - это bash скрипт + команды docker окружения.
Примеры образов: php5.3, python2, python3, apache, nginx + apache + php7

С образами все верно?

С контейнерами плохо разобрался, понял лишь то что:
Контейнер - это изолированная среда, созданная на основе образа.
 
Контейнеров созданных на основе образа может быть сколько угодно много.
Контейнер нельзя изменять изнутри т.к. он всегда создается и удаляется заново при запуске/остановке.
Контейнер кофигурируется снаружи.
Примеры контейнеров:
py2_container1 #Контейнер основанный на образе python2
py2_container2 #Еще один контейнер основанный на образе python2 
php5_container1 #Контейнер основанный на образе php5 
php7_container1 #Контейнер основанный на образе php7

С контейнерами все верно?

Главная проблема - это не понимание как контейнеры друг с другом должны кофигурироваться и как работать с контейнерами которые не являются серверами.

Например у меня есть запущенные контейнеры:
apache2_container1
php7_container1
mysql_container1
Как их друг с другом сконфигурировать чтобы apache нашел php, а php нашел mysql?

И последнее: как работать с контейнером у которого образ не является сервером?
Например есть контейнер python3_container, и у меня есть какой нибудь python скрипт который вычисляет числа Фибоначчи, как это скрипт запустить в контейнере python3_container?

Comment: Здесь можно про то что такое слои, образы и контейнеры https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот тут есть ответы на некоторые ваши вопросы:

- [Как правильно использовать Docker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/601351/215007)
- [Различие между терминами “слой” и “контейнер” в Docker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611977/215007)
- [Что включать в Docker-образ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612336/215007)

**Как контейнеры друг с другом должны конфигурироваться?**

- при запуске контейнера можно указать связанный контейнер и тогда его адрес будет известен внутри контейнера
- можно использовать **docker-compose** и указать связи внутри **docker-compose.yml**
- можно использовать [Обнаружение сервисов (Service Discovery)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

**Как работать с контейнерами которые не являются серверами?**

Так же как и с серверами. Только эти контейнеры будет выдавать результат и после завершать свою работу, а не работать долго, как это делают сервера.

В вашем примере, после вывода на печать/сохранения в файл/посылке по сети вычисленного члена ряда Фибоначчи, контейнер завершит свою работу и будет остановлен.